# Should I delete SNS endpoints for GCM?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

According to the [GCM Advanced Topics](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg), under the part of "How unregistration works", GCM notifies the 3rd-party server that a registration id is no longer registered with the device. When we use Amazon SNS, the 3rd-party is Amazon. What I'm unclear on is SNS does when when GCM sends it `NotRegistered` for a registration id.

Does Amazon delete the SNS topic? If so, how do I know on my application server to remove my reference to it? If not, how am I expected to clean up my list of SNS topics assigned to a user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Amazon SNS sets the endpoint to "Disabled". You can subscribe to [EventEndpointCreated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetPlatformApplicationAttributes.html) events to receive this notification.

From the [Amazon SNS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/):

> **How does SNS Mobile Push handle token feedback from notification services?**
>
> SNS Mobile Push automatically handles token feedback services on your behalf, and exposes the feedback information via events published to a topic you may choose to consume. This approach reduces the operational burden of sending push notifications, and maximizes the speed and reliability with which your notifications are delivered. Push notifications services such as APNS and GCM provide feedback about tokens which may have expired or been replaced by new tokens. When a particular token is replaced by a new token, SNS automatically updates the associated endpoint, and notifies you via an event. When a particular token expires, perhaps because a user deleted your app, SNS marks the endpoint as disabled and notifies you via an event. You don’t strictly need to consume the feedback notifications in order to send push notifications with SNS, but may choose to do so based on your broader use case.

Comment: I can't find any documentation about the 'EndpointUpdated' event - the link does not work anymore. Is there an updated version available?

Comment: @domi I updated the link. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetPlatformApplicationAttributes.html